# SharePoint App resources files not being included on deployment

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, visual-studio-2013

I have a SharePoint App that has a lot of resource files (js, css, imgs, etc.) that are not being included when I deploy the project. The weird thing is that 2 days ago everything was working fine and now they aren't...

I've been playing with the 'Items in the solution' and 'Items in the feature' lists. I also have two features which I'm not sure is a good or bad thing...

**Error**

[image: 404]

**Feature1**

[image: Feature1]

**Feature2 - Has been removed** 
[image: Feature2]

The folders that are missing are Views, Content, and template but the Script folder is loading fine. Any help would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I have removed Feature 2 and ensured all resources are associated to Feature 1. still having same issue.

Comment: Post the elements xml content.